# Limit number of records getting from `views_get_view_result()` in drupal 7 to do a pagination

Tags: php, ajax, drupal-7, drupal-views

In my `Drupal 7` website, I am using `views_get_view_result` function to get some details from the database.

**Right now I am calling the function like below**

```
$table_data = views_get_view_result('test_tracking', 'block', <nid>);
```

**And this function is calling through ajax**

I am now able to get this as an array of objects. **But I don't want to get all the data at a time. Is there any way to fetch data with count?** So that I will be able to get the slice of the array. I don't want to use `array_slice` in PHP. Because it will fetch all the data first and then slice it.

I checked the [Official doc](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_get_view_result/7.x-3.x) but it didn't help.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

To fetch data with limit and offset,

```
$table_data = views_get_view('test_tracking');
$table_data->set_display('block');
$table_data->set_current_page(3);
$table_data->set_items_per_page(10);
$table_data->pre_execute();
$table_data->execute();
//To render
print $table_data->render();
// To get the result object
$objects = $table_data->result;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time. May I know how can I pass the `nid` with this?

Comment: Before calling the pre_execute(), please pass the node id like $table_data->args = array(nid); Hope it will help

Comment: Perfect. I am getting the data. But still not paginated. I give `set_current_page` as 1 and `set_items_per_page` as 2. But still, it fetching all records. I have 5 records in total.

Comment: I tried to print `$table_data->result`. But it showing 5 records

Comment: Please check the version of your module.Please remove $table_data->pre_execute(); this line and check.

Comment: I am using 7.x. Removed that line and still, getting the same result.

Comment: +1 upvote question and answer - excellent answer.  This is really useful for programmatically getting batches/subsets/sections/chunks of a Drupal View display's results, being able handle those chunks one at a time. This is useful for performance and resource constraints. I have an application which has 100,000 nodes. So being able to load these in sections and iterate these in smaller management chunks means I won't run out of memory holding all of them at once. Handling in chunks means I could also more easily report progress via a visual meter (Terminal or web UI).

Comment: The Drupal 9 equivalent would be implementing using: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21src%21ViewExecutable.php/class/ViewExecutable/9.0.x